# mysqli_real_escape_string неправильно экранирует

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli

```
INSERT INTO reviews

(userName, email, phone, review_text,ip,browser)

VALUES('$userName','$email','$phone','$review_text','$userData[ip]','$userData[browser]')
```

вот строка  которую передаю в `real escape string`

в БД не записывается. Запрос работает если из него \ убирать, после обработки 
`real escape string`.

Comment: В чем может быть проблема подскажет кто?

Answer (score 3):

Так делать не нужно, нужно каждую переменную оборачивать в функцию отдельно, а так-же, желательно обрамлять поля в тильду **`**

```
$userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($userName);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($email);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($phone);
$review_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($review_text);
$ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($userData['ip']);
$browser = mysqli_real_escape_string($userData['browser']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `reviews` (`userName`, `email`, `phone`, `review_text`,`ip`,`browser`)
VALUES('" . $userName . "','" . $email . "','" . $phone . "','" . $review_text . "','" . $ip . "','" . $browser . "')";
```

А вообще, конечно - лучше использовать `prepared`- подготавливаемые запросы:

```
$stmt = $stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO `reviews` (`userName`, `email`, `phone`, `review_text`,`ip`,`browser`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $userName);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $email);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $phone);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $review_text);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $userData['ip']);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $userData['browser']);
$stmt->execute();
```

В данном случае `mysqli_real_escape_string` делать не нужно, так-как - это делается внутри движка.